# call another contract in remix browser does not work as expected

Tags: solidity, remix

I am not expert in Solidity. I am trying to call a function to another contract so that it updates values but it does not. I am using online Remix Browser. 
The contract to be called is Supreme. I can see that getter and setter values are working as expected. The caller contract is Hack. If Sneak function from Contract Hack sends 1 ether more than the value of cost then  the sender becomes big . For example, if Sneak calls function Supreme with Cost = 2 ether then Cost becomes 2 sender replaces takes the position of 'big'.
When I pass address from first contract to Caller contract and give 2 ethers in value. Click on setter, then I check cost, it remains 1 ether. I tried so many ways but I am not able to move forward.

```
contract Supreme {
    address public big;
    uint256 public cost;

    function Supreme() 
      public
    {
        big = msg.sender;
        cost = 3 ether;
    }

    function Road() 
      external
      payable
    {
        require(msg.value >= cost);
        big.transfer(msg.value);
        big = msg.sender;

        cost += 1 ether;
    }
}
```

This is caller contract

```
    import "browser/Supreme.sol";
contract Hack{
Supreme public sup;

Supreme s;
function Hack(Supreme _sup){
    sup = _sup;
}
function sneak(address addr) public payable{
 s.Road.value(msg.value)();
  }
   function() payable{
   s.Road(); 
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. It doesn't look like you're ever creating an instance of `Supreme`, so I believe you're trying to send these function calls to address 0.
2. You're not sending any ether when you call `s.Road()`.

For the first issue, you can either have your contract deploy `Supreme`:

```
sup = new Supreme();
```

or (more likely what you want) you can deploy `Supreme` yourself and then pass the address of the deployed contract to `Hack` in the constructor:

```
function Hack(Supreme _sup) {
    sup = _sup;
}
```

To fix the second issue, add a value to your call:

```
s.Road.value(msg.value)();
```

---

**EDIT**

Your new code has different issues. It keeps track of `sup` but then doesn't use it. The `sneak` function also takes an address which is unused.

Here's fixed code. Be sure to pass the address of the deployed `Supreme` contract when you create `Hack`. That means you need to enter the address of that contract (like `"0x123abc..."`) in the text field next to the "Create" button. Then send ether by changing the `value` field in the upper right when you call the `sneak` function.

```
import "browser/Supreme.sol";
contract Hack {
    Supreme public sup;

    function Hack(Supreme _sup) public {
        sup = _sup;
    }

    function sneak() public payable {
        sup.Road.value(msg.value)();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @smarx. I changed Hack contract as you advised. However, I am still not able to see the expected results. I noticed that on the left hand side of Remix Browser, there is an error which appears when I click  setter 'Sneak'. I am passing address as well as 3 ethers. Here is the error: transact to Hack.sneak errored: Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or ']' after array element at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data

Comment: If I provide only ethers(3) and not passing address as Input to Hack with the supposition that Hack would probably pick up the address automatically, then I get the following error: transact to Hack.sneak errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value. Debug the transaction to get more information

Comment: See my edit. I'm confused about what you tried, but hopefully my updated code helps you.

Comment: Thanks @smarx. I used the same code as you have provided above. When I click on create button after providing address copied from Supreme contract.  It does not show me sneak or any setter/getter. Instead, I am getting the following error: creation of Hack errored: Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or ']' after array element at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what you're putting in the field next to "Create?" It should be a hexadecimal string starting with `0x` and enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: I am putting 0xdc04977a2078c8ffdf086d618d1f961b6c546222 in the field next to  'Create'. I copied it from 'Supreme at 0xdc04977a2078c8ffdf086d618d1f961b6c546222(memory)'

Comment: Are you missing the double quotes? Are you sure you're deploying the right contract (`Hack`)? Are you sure that `Hack` only takes one constructor parameter?

Comment: yes double quote was missing. I was unaware of it. Thank you so much for solving my issue.